# como crear una función tiempo en python?

Tags: python

como crear una función tiempo en Python? gracias!

Comment: Lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) <-- . Pon el código que hayas hecho, que has probado, dinos donde tienes el problema...

Comment: ¿Que es una función tiempo?¿Una función que te mata lentamente, te envejece y reduce tu resistencia al alcohol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no hay un código de referencia, daré una respuesta genérica. Para poder saber cuánto tiempo transcurre desde el inicio de la partida hasta el final podrías hacer algo así:

```
import time
#inicia la partida
tiempo_inicial = time.time()
#sucede algo
#finaliza la partida
tiempo_final = time.time()
print(tiempo_final-tiempo_inicial)
```

PD: el resultado es en segundos.